# MATLAB: Inverting a boolean value quickly

Tags: matlab, boolean

Is there a quicker way than the following to 'flip' a true or false to its opposite state?

```
if x == true
 x = false;
else
 x = true;
end
```

Yes, perhaps only five lines of code is nothing to worry about but something that looks more like this would be fantastic:

```
x = flip(x);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
x = ~x;
```

Comment: Wow. That's even shorter than I could have dreamed of. I should get out more. Thanks

Comment: If you want to get out more, head over to the online Matlab doco (run `doc()`) and check out the MATLAB > Functions > Programming and Data Types > Logical Operations section. It has a bunch of operators like this. :)

Answer (score 6):

u can use negation statement.
I cant remember how it works in matlab, but i think is something like

```
x = ~x;
```

Answer (score 6):

Franck's answer is better (using ~), but I just wanted to point out that the conditional in *yours* is slightly redundant.  It's easy to forget that, since you already have a boolean value, you don't need to perform a comparison in your conditional.  So you could have just done this...

```
if x
  x = false;
else
  x = true;
end
```

Comment: Note that this (and OP's code) is only correct if `x` is scalar. If x is nonscalar, there's an implicit `all(x)` around it when used in a boolean context, like as the argument to `if`. For example, if `x` is `[1 1 1 0]`, it'll be treated as false, and replaced with `true`. The `~` operator is elementwise, so it'll work with arrays. (Except empty arrays when used with `if`; that's a separate edge case.)